# What are the various ways to hide a <div>?

Tags: css

Right, I am a CSS noob. I am trying to collate the various ways to hide a div.

For example:

```
display:none;
visibility:hidden;
```

Are there any more esoteric ones?

forget about JQuery, JavaScript, events...  I just to know the various CSS ways that a div with lots content and sub div can end up hidden?

The reason why I want this is because I am looking at some code here and a div is invisible.  Why I don't know?  It might be something in the parent div.

The div has various classes and this one looks like the offender -

```
.div-content {

    position: absolute;
    left: 70px;
    right: 0;
    top: 55px;
    bottom: 0;

    display: block;

    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;

    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;

    /*width: 90%;*/

    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: #F8F7F7;

}
```

I narrowed it down to this class by just commenting in and out various other classes. When this class is commented out - I can see the div.

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: Side point - note the difference between ways of hiding elements: To use your examples, `display: none;` hides the element and other content will occupy its space (as though the element was never there), whilst `visibilty: hidden;` will hide the element but it will still occupy its portion of the screen (as though it's there but invisible)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Several possibilities:

- **`display: none`** - This will cause the browser to not render it. It would also make it completely vanish from screen readers as well, so beware.
- **`visibility: hidden`** - This will cause the browser to render it, it wouldn't be visible, but would leave a space corresponding to the element's size.
- **`position: absolute` and the send it to a ridiculous location (for example, `left: -99999px`; assuming parent's `overflow` isn't set to `auto` or `scroll`).** - This works well when you want the element not actually visible, but still exist in the source or the DOM.
- **Set `width` and `height` to 0, and ensure `overflow: hidden`** - Same as above, the element would be completely invisible, but still exist at the DOM or source.
- **`opacity: 0`** - Would achieve the same effect of `visibility: hidden` only through different means (i.e. changing the actual opacity of the element).

---

Now this all depends on *why* you need it.

- Do you want to make the element completely disappear? `display: none` (and making it reappear with `display: block`) is your choice.
- Do you want to animate it? Going with `opacity: 0` or `width`&`height` is probably a better choice, perhaps with some JavaScript.
- Want it to be accessible to screen readers, but not actually visible (for example, hidden image captions?), going with `position: absolute; left: -99999px` works well.

Comment: And don't forget `font: 0/0;` ;)

Comment: @HashemQolami: Would fail if there are other elements (especially images) inside :)

Comment: I meant adding this when in order to hide text.

Comment: @HashemQolami: Not required, as `overflow: hidden` would make sure that even if there is something with size inside, it would disappear. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ47c/)

Comment: @MoreThanFive: That class alone isn't enough to make the div disappear. Please construct a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which shows the problem clearly.

Comment: many properties are wrong in in this class but we cant give the exact solution before knowing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good practice though, you can use

```
opacity:0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why do you ask question like that, but here is another way to hide an element:

```
element.style {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

```
element.style {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000000px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or we can use css transform property as well and set its axis. This can possibly hide your element.

Comment: i would be great if you show example and code also not just typing text that rather be in comment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).